Issue Google Sheets Query: Auto expand rows on protected sheets with QUERY function
If a user only only have edit access to specific cells, the user cannot add rows to the sheet and so the QUERY function cannot auto expand needed rows on ends up with an #REF error.
Output: #REF - Result was not automatically exoanded, please insert more rows (3).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110oHPBnzlC16vE408ImCy0i6UrDNzRNBMKzku4m6quo/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Is there a way to resolve this behavior without using an AppScript onEdit installable Trigger which runs under the sheets owner, checking the cell for a #REF error and adding more cells via AppScript?

[Edit] relevant info from comments into questions.

Have you tried range protection instead of sheet protection?

When using range protection, the user can edit the new auto inserted rows. When a user accidentally entered a value in one of these new added rows, the QUERY cannot deliver results because it would overwrite the value in the accidentally edited cell.

What is your issue with AppScript onEdit installable Trigger? Maybe you could a service account? Or display the results in a modal dialog? Or go the full webapp route.

The problem with a installable trigger is: It can be only fired by onEdit oder onOpen.  A script ran via a menu or a clicked image (button) always runs under the privileg of the current sheet user. When a script, ran from a menu or a button , fills in a query string in the sheet, onEdit trigger does not recognize this change on the sheet.

When a script, ran from a menu or a button , fills in a query why not make the same script call to see if there's a ref error after inputting the query? And then add more rows. In this case, to bypass protection, a service account with privileges can be used.

Because a script runs always on the privileges of the current sheet user. The user cannot add rows, so it's also impossible he can add rows via a script. Or is it possible that a user can run a AppScript with the privilegs of the sheet owner? I think it's not possible (except onEdit or onOpen Trigger which connect triggered by a menu or a button click).

Service accounts are accounts owned by an app.  You can provide the service account with extra privileges(by sharing the sheet with edit privileges) and then use oauth  to run as service account: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs (no need to impersonate in your case)

Kindly consider checking the link that TheMaster has provided.

My solution

A sheets formula is checking for #REF! error in cell A4
The sheets formula is printing "Please reload Sheet/refresh browser window"
An installable onOpen trigger (running at owner privilegs) is checking cell A4 for #REF! error and is adding 1000 more rows
At the end, script deletes all unused rows

DONE

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly provide more details so that everyone in the community who may see it, can understand it well.
